# intent function is not working correctly

Tags: android, android-intent

im facing a problem that is im sending a line number from phone activity through putExtra and received the value in dial activity. 1st time the getIntent function received right value but in 2nd time he could not received the right value. The 1st vale is show in 2nd time .

phone Activity

```
    public class Phone extends Activity 
{


    List<Map<String, String>> data;

    Map<String, String> Line1;
    Map<String, String> Line2;
    Map<String, String> Line3;
    Map<String, String> Line4;
    Map<String, String> Line5;

    ListView Lines = null;

    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        m_objPhone = this;

        String sPhoneAccountStatus = VaxStatus.m_objVaxStatus.GetPhoneAccountStatus();
        m_objPhoneAccountStatus.setText(sPhoneAccountStatus);

        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        Line1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Line1.put("title", "Line | 1" );
        Line1.put("status", "");

        data.add(Line1);


       Line2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Line2.put("title", "Line | 2" );
        Line2.put("status", "");
        data.add(Line2);

        Line3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Line3.put("title", "Line | 3" );
        Line3.put("status", "");
        data.add(Line3);

        Line4 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Line4.put("title", "Line | 4" );
        Line4.put("status", "");
        data.add(Line4);

       Line5 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Line5.put("title", "Line | 5" );
        Line5.put("status", "");
        data.add(Line5);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

        Lines.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (int nLineNo = 0; nLineNo < VaxSIPUserAgent.TOTAL_LINE_COUNT; nLineNo++)
        {
            String sLineStatus = VaxStatus.m_objVaxStatus.GetLineStatus(nLineNo);
            SetStatus(nLineNo, sLineStatus);
        }


        Lines.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                switch (arg2) 
                {
                    case 0: 
                        ShowDialPad(arg2, null);

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ShowDialPad(arg2, null);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ShowDialPad(arg2, null);

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ShowDialPad(arg2, null);

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ShowDialPad(arg2, null);

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        for (int nLineNo = 0; nLineNo < VaxSIPUserAgent.TOTAL_LINE_COUNT; nLineNo++)
        {
            String sLineStatus = VaxStatus.m_objVaxStatus.GetLineStatus(nLineNo);
            SetStatus(nLineNo, sLineStatus);
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {
        VaxPhone.m_objVaxVoIP.IsMuteMic();
        VaxPhone.m_objVaxVoIP.IsMuteSpk();

        IncommingCallSlider.m_objCallSlider.SetActiveActivity(this, R.id.PhoneRelativeLayout);
        IncommingCallRing.m_objIncommingCallRing.SetActiveActivity(this);

        DialCallTone.m_objDialCallTone.SetActiveActivity(this);

        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
        VaxPhone.m_objVaxVoIP.SetSpeakerState(m_objcheckSpkPhone.isChecked());

        super.onStop();
   }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        VaxStatus.m_objVaxStatus.SetPhoneActivity(null);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void OnEndCall(int nLineNo)
    {   
        SetStatus(nLineNo, "Ready To Use!");

    }

    public static void OnContactPhoneNo(String sPhoneNo)
    {
        int nFreeLineNo = VaxPhone.m_objVaxVoIP.GetFreeLine();
        m_objPhone.ShowDialPad(nFreeLineNo, sPhoneNo);
    }


   public void ShowDialPad(int nFreeLineNo, String sPhoneNo) 
   {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Phone.this , DialPad.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
       intent.putExtra("LineNo", nFreeLineNo);
       intent.putExtra("PhoneNo", sPhoneNo);
       startActivity(intent);

   }

   public void OnStatusPhone(int nLineNo, String sStatusMsg)
   {
       for (int LineNo = 0; LineNo < VaxSIPUserAgent.TOTAL_LINE_COUNT; LineNo++)
       {
           String sLineStatus = VaxStatus.m_objVaxStatus.GetLineStatus(LineNo);
           SetStatus(LineNo, sLineStatus);
       }

       if(m_objDialPad != null)
           m_objDialPad.OnStatusPhone(sStatusMsg);
   }

   public void OnStatusAccount(String sStatusMsg)
   {
       m_objPhoneAccountStatus.setText(sStatusMsg);

       if(m_objDialPad != null)
           m_objDialPad.OnStatusAccount(sStatusMsg);
   }




    public void showSelectedNumber(String number) 
    {
        Phone.OnContactPhoneNo(number);
    }

    void SetStatus(int nLineNo, String sStatusMsg)
    {
        if(nLineNo == 0)
        {
            Line1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Line1.put("title", "Line | 1" );
            Line1.put("status", sStatusMsg);
            data.set(0, Line1);

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        if(nLineNo == 1)
        {
            Line2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Line2.put("title", "Line | 2" );
            Line2.put("status", sStatusMsg);
            data.set(1, Line2);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        if(nLineNo == 2)
        {
            Line3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Line3.put("title", "Line | 3" );
            Line3.put("status", sStatusMsg);
            data.set(2, Line3);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        if(nLineNo == 3)
        {
            Line4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Line4.put("title", "Line | 4" );
            Line4.put("status", sStatusMsg);
            data.set(3, Line4);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        if(nLineNo == 4)
        {
            Line5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Line5.put("title", "Line | 5" );
            Line5.put("status", sStatusMsg);
            data.set(4, Line5);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

dial Activity

```
public class DialPad extends Activity 
{
    private TextView m_objStatus;
    private Button m_objBtnDial; 




    int m_nLineNo = -1;
    boolean m_objContactFlag;

    public static Phone m_objPhone;
    private static String[] m_objPhoneNum = new String[VaxSIPUserAgent.TOTAL_LINE_COUNT];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Phone.m_objDialPad = this;

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int nIntentExtraLineNo = intent.getIntExtra("LineNo", 1);
        m_nLineNo = nIntentExtraLineNo; 



        final int [] aLineArray =  new int[VaxSIPUserAgent.TOTAL_LINE_COUNT - 1];

        int nIndex = 0;

        for (int nLineNo = 0; nLineNo < VaxSIPUserAgent.TOTAL_LINE_COUNT; nLineNo++)
        {
            if(m_nLineNo ==  nLineNo)
                continue;

            aLineArray[nIndex] =  nLineNo + 1;
            nIndex++;

        }

        String sLineStatus = VaxStatus.m_objVaxStatus.GetLineStatus(m_nLineNo);
        OnStatusPhone(sLineStatus);


             String sPhoneNo = intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNo");

        if(sPhoneNo != null)
        {
            m_objPhoneNum[nIntentExtraLineNo] = sPhoneNo;
        }

        m_objEditDialscreen.setText(m_objPhoneNum[nIntentExtraLineNo]);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {



        UpdateDialBtn();


        if(m_objContactFlag == false)
            m_objEditDialscreen.setText(m_objPhoneNum[m_nLineNo]);

        IncommingCallSlider.m_objCallSlider.SetActiveActivity(this, R.id.dialpad);
        IncommingCallRing.m_objIncommingCallRing.SetActiveActivity(this);

        DialCallTone.m_objDialCallTone.SetActiveActivity(this);

        super.onStart();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
        m_objPhoneNum[m_nLineNo] = m_objEditDialscreen.getText().toString();
        super.onStop();
    }


 }
```

Comment: is this all the code of `Phone.java` class?

Comment: check whether you passing same `sPhoneNo and nFreeLineNo` at second time too

Comment: Do you have any flags in DialPad Activity in AndroidManifest, like SINGLE_TOP or smth else. If so onCreate may not be called. In this case you must override onNewIntent() method in activity.

Comment: check whether you are passing Integer value in putExtra or is it a string..

Comment: what is nFreeLineNo and sPhoneNo is it int or string if is int then you have to getIntExtra("key", 1) otherwise getStringExtra("key").

Comment: Hamid shatu No its not a all code of phone class

Comment: Sathish Kumar both are passing at same time but received one by one

Comment: Nepster both are integer value. There a 5 line in phone activity one u press these line the dial activity is open.

Comment: @user3136235 sorry i am not get you. Try post `ShowDialPad()` method calling code too

Comment: check again i update the phone class

Comment: You really need to trim the amount of code in this post to the relevant parts. You can't expect people to read through all of this!

Answer (score 0):

`Phone` activity starts the `DialPad` activity using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. This means that if there is already an active (non-finished) instance of `DialPad` in the task stack, this instance of the activity will simply be moved to the front (top of the activity stack). In this case, `onCreate()` **will not be called** on `DialPad`, because it isn't recreating the activity. Instead `onNewIntent()` will be called. You have not overridden this method in `DialPad` so you will not see this method call.

Since you are extracting `LineNo` and `PhoneNo` from the Intent extras in `onCreate()`, you will always use only the data that you get from the first `Intent`. This is exactly the problem that you are seeing.

To fix it, override `onNewIntent()` and extract `LineNo` and `PhoneNo` from the extras that are passed in the `Intent` argument that you receive in `onNewIntent()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a Bundle object and then pass it through intent.putExtras(bundle), this is the proper way to pass extras through an intent (I understand nFreeLineNo is an int and sPhoneNo a String):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Phone.this , DialPad.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("LineNo", nFreeLineNo);
b.putString( "PhoneNo", sPhoneNo);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, in DialPad getExtras like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
//Make sure you passed a bundle
if (b != null){
    m_nLineNo = b.getInt("LineNo");
    m_sPhoneNo = b.getString("PhoneNo");
}else{
     //didnt pass bundle, Do what you want
}
```

Hope I helped you, I also had this problem and solved this way

If this not helped you, please post error stacktrace from Logcat

Comment: Please, post stacktrace then. Otherwise, I cannot help

Comment: This is a useless answer. Extras is already a `Bundle`. You can add primitives and `String` extras simply by using `putExtra()` (which OP is already doing). Putting those extras into an additional `Bundle` and then calling `putExtras()` to copy that data from the one `Bundle` into the extras `Bundle` is simply overhead that doesn't accomplish anything. At the end it is exactly the same as what OP was already doing (which is why this answer doesn't solve his problem).